# usr/bin directory is not showing up in attached volume in gcp

Tags: google-cloud-platform, snapshot, gcp-ai-platform-training

GCP:
I've created a snapshot of an VM using boot disk, and then i created a volume from this snapshot and attached and mount the volume to another VM.
In the mount path, i don't find the /usr/bin directory.

The VM from which i've created the snapshot is running on COS(container optimize operating system).

Answer (score 1):

`/usr/bin` contains executable files **that are not part** of the core operating system. These are considered to be *system wide binaries*. Since certain directories are excluded from snapshots, files belonging to these users will remain in the file system.

`/bin` contains executable files **that are part** of the core operating system. These files need to be accessible before `/usr` gets mounted. (for instance, the mount command is in `/bin/mount`).

If the snapshot was created from a boot disk that was formatted with a filesystem that does not include the `/usr/bin` directory, then the volume will not have the `/usr/bin directory` either. **Reformat** the volume with a filesystem that includes the /usr/bin directory. You can do this using the [mkfs.ext4](https://hopeness.medium.com/master-the-linux-mkfs-ext4-command-a-comprehensive-guide-a727c9a9e03) command from the Medium blog written by **Peter Hou**. Also,you can refer to the [linode community page](https://www.linode.com/community/questions/17599/my-block-storage-device-is-not-listed-on-devdiskby-id) replies from **bellis** and **dwfreed** for more details.

Once the volume has been reformatted, you can mount it again and the `/usr/bin directory` will be present.

Comment: Thanks for you response, To add more details in the questions, I've taken the snapshot of the COS(container optimize operating system) in GCP, As i'm creating  a persistent disk from the snapshot, so i don't need to create a file system after attaching the disk to a VM. I'm not able to determine where can i find the executables (/usr/bin and /bin) directories.

Comment: When you create a volume from a snapshot, the volume is created with the same data as the snapshot. However, the volume is not attached to a VM, so it is not mounted. To mount the volume, you must attach it to a VM. Once the volume is attached, you can mount it using the **mount** command.

Comment: To access the **/usr/bin directory**, try installing the **binutils package**. This package includes the **ls command**, which you can use to list the files in the /usr/bin directory. To install the binutils package, run this command: **sudo apt-get install binutils**.

Comment: I've attached and mounted the volume, but looks like the issue is specific to COS ref: https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/concepts/disks-and-filesystem, when i followed the same steps for a VM with ubuntu, i don't see any issue and /usr and /bin directories are showing up.